# Custom ErrorDocument stopped working when using another redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I am new to .htaccess syntax so I'm not sure why one part is affecting the other. Here is my entire .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/$ books/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ books/$1
```

When I only had the ErrorDocument parts in, the 404 and 500 pages worked perfectly. Then I added the remaining code and THAT part works 100% as intended (it makes [www.example.com/books/mybook](http://www.example.com/books/mybook) look like [www.example.com/mybook](http://www.example.com/mybook)), but for some reason it causes my 404 and 500 error pages to default to the regular white 500 error page and won't go to the custom ones. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since the error pages have nothing to do with the books directory. All other subdirectories work as intended and were not affected by my rewrite rules. Can someone help me understand why the ErrorDocuments won't work in conjunction with this rewrite rule?

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, so you mean you are hitting link `http://www.example.com/books/mybook` and want it to become like `http://www.example.com/mybook` on browser? Please confirm once. Thank you.

Comment: Yes! It works perfect around the whole site unless I am getting a 404 error. Then it turns into a 500 error and doesn't go to the custom 500 error page.